# Python code that shows time. Want to add apostrophe(‘) at the beginning and end of output

Tags: python

E.g task8(61) should return '1 hour, 1 minute' exactly

```
def task8(x):
    hours_total = x // 60
    minutes_total = x % 60
    
    if minutes_total == 1:
        minutes = "minute"
    else :
        minutes = "minutes"
    if hours_total == 1:
        hours = "hour,"
    else :
        hours = "hours,"
    print (hours_total,hours,minutes_total,minutes)
task8(61)
```

Comment: According to your post, your function is supposed to _return_, not _print_.

Comment: Use a string formatting method, such as `.format()`, `%` or f-string.

Comment: see e.g. [what is the purpose of the return statement? how is it different from printing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129285/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-return-statement-how-is-it-different-from-printing)

Comment: You seem to have confused printing and returning so I've closed your question as a duplicate. You'll want to use string formatting as well, like Barmar said. If you need tips on that, you could check out the official tutorial: [Fancier Output Formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting)

Answer (score 0):

Why not making a string to print? Like this...

```py
print(f"'{hours_total} {hours}, {minutes_total} {minutes}'")
```

This way you can even remove the ',' from the HOURS and MINUTES.

To understand more about [f in a string](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals).

Comment: In your case, just return the string... 

**return (f"'{hours_total} {hours}, {minutes_total} {minutes}'")**

Comment: Thanks for the answer! If you have more to add to your answer, it's best to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74059892/edit) it to improve/clarify rather than appending to your answer in comments. no need to highlight changes to your original post - just edit the text directly to make it as clear/informative as possible. see the guide to [answer].

Answer (score 0):

Simply just format the outputs. Convert integer to string and add "'" at start and end.

```
def task8(x): 
    hours_total = x // 60 
    minutes_total = x % 60
    if minutes_total == 1:
        minutes = " minute"
    else :
        minutes = " minutes"
    if hours_total == 1:
        hours = " hour,"
    else :
        hours = " hours,"
    print("'"+str(hours_total)+hours+str(minutes_total)+minutes+"'")

task8(61)
```

Comment: please don't ask for reputation/upvotes in your answer or comments - just stick to the substance. thanks!